# Plomino multilingual site

Tags: multilingual, plone-4.x

I've got Zope 2.13.15, Plone 4.2.0.1, LinguaPlone 4.1.3 and CMFPlomino 1.17.2

I need to make a multilingual website on Plone and am using Plomino. I see that I can translate plomino database, forms and views with LinguaPlone but not documents. I have seen the procedure on http://www.plomino.net/how-to/multilingual-applications (Multilingual applications - How to build a multilingual Plomino application) and more detailed on https://github.com/plomino/Plomino/issues/296. I'm not sure can I translate content of documents using this procedure because the mentioned tutorial states "If the text does not match any msgid from the i18n domain, it remains unchanged".

Does this mean that all the translations of the content of documents should be in the .po files or what. Can anybody clear this mechanism to me please and is this tutorial the right way to document content translation ?? At this moment I'm not sure if there is a document content translation solution for Plomino
What is the procedure to translate document content in Plomino? The tutorials are not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no document content translation solution for Plomino.
The mentioned solution can be used to translate pre-defined contents (like labels in forms, computed values, etc.) but obviously it is not applicable to content freely entered by users in documents.

Nevertheless, Plomino is already used in multilingual contexts.

A basic solution is to:

- create a field to store the document language,
- provide a Document ID formula which will use this lang field value (so we can guess the id of any translated version from the current doc id),
- implement the different actions you might need (like "Translate this doc", "Switch to language xx", etc.) as basic Plomino actions.